# EF Codefirst fails to work with partial tables of northwind database

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I could not work with employee table of Northwind database alone.

below code throws error as

> "Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type
>   'Northwind.Order_Detail'. Use the ColumnAttribute or the HasKey method
>   to specify an order for composite primary keys."

but it works fine, if I consider Order_details and other tables as well. and HasKey for OrderDetails table.

My Question is, is it not possible to work with few tables (Employee table alone in this case) using EF.

```
public partial class NorthwindEntities : DbContext
{
    public NorthwindEntities()
        : base("Northwind")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        SetupModels(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Anand

Comment: Hi! Could you show the `Employee` class and the `SetupModels` method? It's likely that `Employee` has a navigation property to order or order details or something.

Answer (score 0):

Master table has navigation property to Order , Order details tables. that causes this error. after removing navigation properties in Employee table, it works fine.